# Group by, Sum in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Есть SQL запрос:

```
Select Organisation, City, SUM(Quantity) as Amount, SUM(Summa) as Summa from C#Table
Group by Organisation, City
```

Нужно его сделать в LINQ.
Пока получилось только что то типа:

```
var query = from data in db.GetTable<TableClass>()
            group data by data.Organisation into result
            select new
            {
                Name = result.Key,                            
                Quantity = result.Sum(i => i.Quantity),
                Summa = result.Sum(i => i.Summa)
           };
```

Comment: что не так в предоставленном коде?

Comment: Не хватает группировки по City

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для группировки по нескольким полям нужно создавать объект, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx#code-snippet-7):

```
var query = from data in db.GetTable<TableClass>()
            group data by new { data.Organisation, data.City } into result
            select new
            {
                Name = result.Key.Organisation,                            
                City = result.Key.City,                            
                Quantity = result.Sum(i => i.Quantity),
                Summa = result.Sum(i => i.Summa)
           };
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: @ТимофейБуланкин, добавил ссылку на справку

Comment: @ТимофейБуланкин можете пометить ответ как верный (галочка слева от ответа).